# Do i loop through or add the number via an Array in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

Thanks to help from others the code below works great it searches for words then highlights them and for every word it finds it ads a 1 in the final column, but as a next step I wanted to add value 1 for textbox1search and 5 for textbox2search, this is so that when i sort every extra word added as i go down it gets a higher value then adds it to the end column the when sorted the highest value goes to the top when i initiate a sort by value.  The question is would i be better doing looping through each time or can this also be done by adding an array with the value and linking it to the existing routine?  I tried looping through each time and not using an array and it took an age.  Can someone give me a pointer please?

This is the working code i have.

```
Worksheets("Questions").Activate
Dim sPos As Long, sLen As Long
Dim SRrng As Range, cell2 As Range
Dim mywords As Variant, myColors As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Set SRrng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:E4000")

With UsrFormSearch ' Think the .Value is superfluous - add back in if issues arise
    mywords = Array(.TxtSearch1, .TxtSearch2, .TxtSearch3, .TxtSearch4, .TxtSearch5)
End With
myColors = Array(RGB(255, 0, 0), RGB(0, 255, 0), RGB(255, 0, 255), RGB(0, 0, 255), RGB(0, 0, 255))

Dim m As Byte
Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

Dim CountArray() As Variant
ReDim CountArray(1 To SRrng.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)

For m = 0 To UBound(mywords)
With ActiveSheet.Range("B2:E4000")
    Set c = .Find(mywords(m), LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            For i = 1 To Len(c.Value)
                sPos = InStr(i, c.Value, mywords(m))
                sLen = Len(mywords(m))
                If (sPos <> 0) Then
                 c.Characters(Start:=sPos, Length:=sLen).Font.Color = myColors(m)
                 c.Characters(Start:=sPos, Length:=sLen).Font.Bold = True
                 i = sPos + Len(mywords(m)) - 1
                 CountArray(c.Row - SRrng.Cells(1, 1).Row + 1, 1) = CountArray(c.Row - SRrng.Cells(1, 1).Row + 1, 1) + 1
                End If
            Next i
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
            If firstAddress = c.Address Then Exit Do
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    End If
End With
Next m
SRrng.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, SRrng.Columns.Count).Resize(UBound(CountArray, 1), 1).Value2 = CountArray
```

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question... So, you already use `CountArray` to add `1` for each occurrence (independent of the textbox text./number) Do you need **adding a different record on the next empty column** (1 for text box 1 and 5 for text box 2...), or **you need adding 5, in case of text box 2**, instead of 1 for all of them, like it happens now, **in the same `CountArray`** ? Anyhow, only text box 1 and 2 should be evaluated in this way? What to be returned in case of text box 3, 4 and 5?

Comment: Your question is on the vague side since you seem to be comparing under-specified hypothetical code with the code that you have posted (and the code that you posted doesn't constitute a [mcve]). In general it is better to move spreadsheet data into a VBA array and process it there, which might be what you are asking about.

Comment: The code counts the number of times it finds a word in a row and adds it to the final column, so if it finds the word "Covid" in a row within a range of B2:E1000 6 times, it puts the number 6 in Column f on the row it finds them and it highlights the words in red so they are visible.  The word "Covid" comes from the array in the code above where it is taken from the textSearch1.  That all works as it is above.

Comment: What im doing now is changing the value that is given to the word so any value from txtsearch1 = a value of 1 any words that i also search the same time that i have typed in txtsearch2 = a value of 4, and if i typed something in txtsearch3 = value of say 7.  This way when i search for the words "Covid" in txtsearch1 box and "Is" in txtsearch2 box and "Awful", in txtsearch3 box then the values in F would total 12.  1 For Covid 4 for Is and 7 for Awful.  So can is use array to store then number and then count them for the number of times it finds the words and apply the different values.  ?

Comment: @FaneDuru,  There are 5 text search boxes in total, and we I can add 5 different words which it will search and for every search it will count by 1 for the words it finds in every row within a range.  What i was trying to do was apply a different value for every search box used. box 1 counts by 1, box 2 counts by 4, box3 counts by 7, box 4 by 9 and box 5 by say 11.  Does that make sense so for box1 the word the could be found 13 times in a row value would be 13 but if i used field 2 for the word time and there was 2 it would be (13 x 1 for "the" and 2 x 4 for "Time") totalling 21